# Typing /0 (not \0) into a lex program causes unexpected behavior

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, lex, lexical-analysis

I made a simple lex program for school, and for some reason it has an unexpected behavior while reading "/0".

The program is as following:

```
%%
[a-z] printf("char %c", yytext[0]-32);
[A-Z] printf("char %c", yytext[0]+32);
([a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+) printf("word %s %lu", yytext, yyleng);
[-][1-9][0-9]* printf("negative integer");
([+][1-9]|[1-9])[0-9]* printf("positive integer");
[-]([1-9][0-9]*|0)[.][0-9]+ printf("negative float");
([+][1-9][0-9]*|[+]0|[1-9][0-9]*|0)[.][0-9]+ printf("positive float");
[-]([1-9][0-9]*|0)[.][0-9]+(e|E)([+]|[-])([0-9]*|0) printf("negative expo");
([+][1-9][0-9]*|[+]0|[1-9][0-9]*|0)[.][0-9]+(e|E)([+]|[-])([1-9][0-9]*|0) printf("positive expo");
[a-zA-Z0-9]+ printf("string");
[ ]+ printf("   ");
. ;
%%
```

While giving it `/0` it identifies it as "string" for unknown reason. I couldn't find any special meaning for this key sequence as its a regular <kbd>/</kbd> and not a <kbd>\</kbd>.

If I replace the digit <kbd>0</kbd> with any other digit it gives me an expected behavior of ignoring the <kbd>/</kbd> key and identifying the digit as "positive integer".

I'll be glad to understand this unexpected behavior.

Comment: No. It echos the `/` and reports the `0` as "string", because you haven't made the leading `+` or `-` optional, so `0` doesn't look look like a number. As a matter of fact these should be in the parser, not the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

`([+][1-9]|[1-9])[0-9]* printf("positive integer");`
This will only accept positive numbers starting with non zero digit, if it's zero, it will go to
`[a-zA-Z0-9]+ printf("string");`

So, if you want `0` or `01` to be accepted as positive number, change the regex for positive number to desired behaviour.